# Django: Cannot save data from Form in Database (MySql)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I've been following a tutorial for Django, but making small changes, doesn't allow me to save the form in Database.

**views.py:**

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            contact = Contact(email=email, subject=subject, message=message).save()
            return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried .create() instead of save()? Save is for updating the data if I am not mistaken.I always use .create() unless I want to update data I use .save()

Also if I were you I would write the code like this

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        Contact.objects.create(email=email, subject=subject, message=message)
        return redirect('contact')
else:
    form = ContactForm()
return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

you don't have to render again just redirect the user